# jquery fetch images from url and provide as zip file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the URLs of a list of images. Now on click of a link, ineed to to zip the images in all those URL's and provide it as a downloadable file. What i have currently done is,

1. Pass the URLs to django views
2. Fetch the images and store it to filesystem
3. Zip them and
4. Return a download dialog as response

Now, i am thinking of doing everything at the client side itself.I came across the JS plugin [Zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/demos/demo1.html) that can zip files. My only problem is how to fetch those images from the URL's and zip them in memory using JS.Any help is appreciated.I also came across other plugins to zip files,

http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/javascriptjquery-zipfilecompressor-plugins/#.UE8cI2AxznA

https://raw.github.com/Stuk/jszip/master/jszip.js

Comment: Can it? My Chrome does not pass the Zip.js test. You'd better use server side solution.

Comment: http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/javascriptjquery-zipfilecompressor   -this page has more options to js zipping
plugins/#.UE8cI2AxznA

Comment: https://raw.github.com/Stuk/jszip/master/jszip.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @VisioN said, the zip.js plugin or any other plugins fails some browser tests, the only way to do this will be on the server side.